# Understanding the state argument in the State Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm trying so hard to wrap my head around the State Monad, and I do not understand the following:

Given the implementation of `return` and `(>>=)`, when you say `State $ \s ->....`, where does `s` come from? I mean,  when you start performing `>>= ... >>=`, doesn't it mean that somewhere in your beginning of the chain you somehow have to provide for that initial parameter?

```
newtype State s a=State { runState::s->(a,s) }

 instance Monad (State s) where
        return a=State $ \s->(a,s)
        (>>=) m g=State $ \s -> let (a,s')= runState m s in
                                   runState (g a) s'
```

In `(>>=)` you say `State $ \s -> runState m s`, and I do not get *when* is that initial `(\s -> ...) argument` (with a **REAL** `argument`) called?

Can someone explain, please?

**Later Edit**:

Can someone show me how would the `initial` state be set, let's say if it needs to get a value using `getLine`?

```
main::IO()
main=do
  argument<-getLine
  --how do i set initial state with argument?
  m >> f1 >> f2 >> f3
```

Comment: It is the *initial* state, so one creates functions where the state is passed (and sometimes modified) and passed to the next state.

Comment: We thus take two states, and create a new `State`. A `State` is in fact not the sate, but a *change* of state. We thus create a new change of state that first passes `s` through the first one, and the result `(a, s')` contains the modified state `s'` that is then passed to the next one.

Comment: Think of a `State s a` value as a "state transformer", a machine which can modify the state, when fed with one, and produce a value of type `a` in the process. The concrete, real, initial state is passed when one finally decides to run the monadic computation using `runState myStateValue myInitialState`. This is a typical workflow with monads: you use a lot of `>>=/return` to build a value of type `M a`, and at the very last step you use `runM` to turn that `M a` into some usable type, breaking the monadic abstraction.

Comment: you write `let x = runState st argument` inside your IO do block, or `runState (do { x <- get ; return (x+1) }) 0`. but that is a *new question*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when you say `State $ \s ->....`, where does `s` come from ?

It *will* come from the invocation, when `runState` *will* supply the initial state value to the state-monadic value, to run the combined computation it describes:

```
st = do { x <- get ; return (x+1) }

x = runState st 0    -- x is (1,0)
```

---

I also sense another possible misunderstanding on your part: you write: "*when* is that initial `(\s -> ...) argument` called?" There's no "initial" lambda: the lambdas are all nested inside!

```
do { a <- as; b <- bs; c <- foo b; return c }
```

translates as

```
as >>= (\a -> bs >>= (\b -> foo b >>= (\c -> return c)))
```

so it's not "initial", that's one combined all-enclosing lambda that is called with the initial state!

And then *it* will call

```
let (a,s1) = runState as s0
```

etc. with that "initial" `as` in the `do` block.

Answer (score 2):

the `do` block does not *perform* any stateful computation - it only assembles some smaller stateful computations into one bigger stateful computation. At the `do` level, the actual state does not exist.

It would be simpler and maybe even more accurate if the monad was called "a stateful computation". Or "a function that takes state of type S and returns another state of the same type alongside its actual result". Then you could imagine `>>=` as "combines two functions of the aforementioned type into one, such that the state returned by the first one is be passed as a parameter to the second one".

Comment: my preferred wording is, "a `do` block does not perform, it *describes* a computation *to be* performed." :)

Comment: @WillNess `do` is not different than any other function :) Would you say that `find` "describes finding a value in a foldable" or would you say that `find` "finds a value in a foldable"? :-)

Comment: `do` is *quite* different from any other function, namely it is not a function at all.

Comment: `find`'s source code describes finding a value in a Foldable indeed; trouble is it's not a Haskell value at all. Each line in a `do` block (the portion to the right of `<-`, if present) *is* a Haskell value. that's the difference.

Comment: @WillNess What does "it" refer to in "trouble is it's not a Haskell value at all"? I'm having trouble parsing that phrase in a way that makes it correct.

Comment: @fdreger `find` describes finding a value in a foldable. The (fully saturated) application of `find` (and the evaluation of this expression) is what finds a value in a foldable. Similarly, a `State` action describes the modification of some initial state. The application of that action to an initial state (modulo newtype unwrapping) is what modifies that initial state.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs "`find`'s source code is not a Haskell value" is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

`State` is just a wrapper around functions of type `s -> (a, s)`. `runState` doesn't actually "run" anything; it just gives back the function wrapped by the `State` constructor. You can, however, compare `runState` to the `($)` operator for functions.

```
($)             f  x = f x
runState (State f) s = f s
```

That makes `(=<<) = flip (>>=)` similar to `(<<<) = (.)`; just rather than taking two functions and returning a third function, it takes a function (that returns a `State`) and a `State` and produces a second `State`.

However, we'll make a direct comparison of `(>>=)` to `(>>>) = flip (.)` so that the types align better. (Similarly, you could compare `(.)` to `(=<<)`.)

```
-- f :: t -> a
-- g ::      a -> b
f >>> g =         \t -> let a       = ($)      f     t
                        in            ($)      g     a
-- m :: State s a
-- g ::         a -> State s b
m >>= g = State $ \s -> let (a, s') = runState m     s
                        in            runState (g a) s'
```